# Gitit: Markdown code block syntax not rendered

Tags: markdown, wiki

When adding a code block in a [gitit](https://github.com/jgm/gitit) wiki page, only the following style works:

```
~~~ {.bash}
#!/bin/sh
git push origin master 2>> logit
~~~
```

While the normal markdown syntax below won't be rendered as code block:

````
```
#!/bin/sh
git push origin master 2>> logit
```
````

How to config gitit so it can render code blocks in the markdown format?
Thanks.

Comment: Pandoc's documentation lists two extensions for fenced code blocks: [fenced_code_blocks](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_code_blocks), which uses tildes, and [backtick_code_blocks](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-backtick_code_blocks), which uses backticks. You need to use the later extension. That said, Gitit's documentation makes [mention](https://github.com/jgm/gitit#highlighted-source-code) of `delimited code blocks`, which doesn't exist in Pandoc's documentation. Perhaps Gitit is using an older version of Pandoc?

Comment: Last commit to gitit was 2018... but I think that extension is older... you can override the default with `format: `, see https://github.com/jgm/gitit/#page-metadata but I think the default `markdown` should be fine... so I don't know.